# Silverman-Toeplitz Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation-method, summability-theory

Reading [this paper](http://pdf.medrang.co.kr/kmj/56/kmj056-02-05.pdf) ***On Deferred Statistical Convergence of Sequences*** by Kucukaslan and Yilmazturk published in **KYUNGPOOK Math. J.56(2016), 357-366**

I am stuck at theorem $2.2.7$ I get $\{n^{(1)} ,n^{(2)},n^{(3)}.......n^{(m)},n^{(m+1)}...\}$ is a decreasing sequence of the natural numbers.
At one point it defines a sequence $$b_{n,m}={{n^{(m)}-n^{(m+1)}}\over{n}}; m=0,1,2,...h\\=0 ; \text{otherwise}$$
where $n^{(0)}=n.$ and then says *the matrix satisfies **Silverman-Toeplitz theorem***  so $${1\over {n^{(m)}-n^{(m+1)}}}\cdot \left|\{n^{(m+1)}\lt k\le n^{(m)}: |x_k-l|\ge \epsilon \}\right|\rightarrow 0$$ when $n\rightarrow \infty.$

I cannot find the exact statement of the said theorem and I do not how what is satisfied to come to that conclusion. And it is the conclusive step.

The book *Elements of Fundamental Analysis by Maddox* is referred to but I do not have that either.

Answer (score 3):

[Silverman-Toeplitz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverman%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem) is a result in [summability theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summability_theory) which describes when a matrix summability method is regular. Being *regular* means any convergent sequence is transformed to a sequence which converges to the same limit.

This result can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silverman%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Silverman%E2%80%93Toeplitz_theorem&oldid=772171997)) and in [many books on this topic](http://books.google.com/books?q=silverman+toeplitz+theorem). Since you asked especially about Maddox's Functional Analysis, I'll copy here the formulation from that book - although it is not substantially different from formulations you can find elsewhere. (In fact, I think that the formulation given on Wikipedia is a bit clearer - it's less heavy on symbols and adds also informal descriptions.)

> ... we shall in future consider only matrix transformations on sequence spaces $X$, in the form $$A_n(x)=\sum a_{nk}x_k.$$
>   By $B(X,Y)$ we shall denote the set of all matrices $A$ which map $X$ into $Y$.
>   By $B(X,Y;P)$ we denote that subset of $B(X,Y)$ for which limits or sums are *preserved*. For example, $A\in(c,c;P)$ means that $A_n(x)$ exists for each $n$ whenever $x\in c$ and that $A_n(x)\to l$  whenever $x\to l$.
>
> Now we give some basic results.
>
> **Theorem 3.** (Silverman-Toeplitz) $A\in(c,c;P)$ if and only if
>   (i) $\sup_n \sum |a_{nk}| < \infty$
>   (ii) $a_{nk}\to 0$ ($n\to\infty$, $k$ fixed)
>   (iii) $\sum a_{nk}\to1$ ($n\to\infty$)

If you look at Wikipedia this can be said briefly as: columns converge to zero, row-sums converge to one, absolute row sums are bounded.

---

In your case want to check whether this is true for the matrix
$$b_{n,m}=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{n^{(m)}-n^{(m+1)}}n, & m=0,1,2,\dots,h \\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
where $n^{(m)}$ and $h$ are defined in the paper.

We know that $n=n^{(0)}>n^{(1)}>n^{(2)}>\dots>n^{(h)}>n^{(h+1)}=0$.

Which means that we always have $b_{n,m}>0$ and thus
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty |b_{n,m}| = \sum_{m=0}^\infty b_{n,m} = \frac{n^{(0)}}n = \frac{n}n=1.$$
So from this get that (i) and (iii) are fulfilled.

However, I have to admit that I do not see how we get that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} b_{n,m} = 0$$
from the conditions given in the paper. Unless I missed something, we only know that $p(n)<n$ and that $n^{(k+1)}=p(n^{(k)})$ (with this process stopping as soon as we get $n^{(h+1)}=0$.)

For example, for $m=0$ we should have
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n-p(n)}n.$$
I do not see among assumptions of Theorem 2.2.7 anything about $p(n)$ which implies that this limit is zero. (Of course, I might have missed something.) It seems that we would need $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} p(n)/n =1$ to get the desired conclusion.